# How do you combine two scenes into one scene?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scene, pane

Is there a way to combine two javaFx scenes into one scene (then assign that scene to a stage) or, assign two scenes to a stage simultaneously so they are side by side on a stage.

Aim: I have a scene that shows a calculator, I have a scene that shows a clock. I want to have them side by side (calculator on left, clock on right) on the same stage (without using scene builder).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, a `Stage` can only have one scene. You should put the *root node* that shows each component (i.e. whatever you are setting as the root of each of these scenes) into an `HBox`, and use the `HBox` as the root of the new scene. This is probably easier to answer if you give some idea of how you have structured things, i.e. what kind of class you are using to represent the clock and the calculator.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this in javafx with subscenes, 
a subscene is like a scene that can be added into layouts

you can do something like this

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane layoutOne = new StackPane();
        Label labelOne = new Label("One");
        layoutOne.getChildren().add(labelOne);
        SubScene subSceneOne = new SubScene(layoutOne,300,100);

        StackPane layoutTwo = new StackPane();
        Label labelTwo = new Label("Two");
        layoutTwo.getChildren().add(labelTwo);
        SubScene subSceneTwo = new SubScene(layoutTwo,300,100);

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(subSceneOne,subSceneTwo);
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root,300,210);
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

hope this what you were looking for, you can also check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html) for more

Comment: Why though? Why not get rid of the subscenes and just do `root.getChildren().addAll(layout1, layout2);`?

Comment: Yes indeed in this case he doesn't need that, because he can just include the parents of the two scenes in the same layout
But I needed subscenes while working with the 3D Api, subscenes will be so useful if you try to combine a 2D scene with a 3D scene
You will need a 3D subscene (with depth test enabled and antialiasing if you want) and then add it on a layout from the 2D scene. Someone might find this useful.